# Is there a pretty way to get current op id to watch MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to watch a collection in MongoDB.

Do you know list-watch in k8s? They are similar - Firstly, I want to invoke a function `list` to get all data and a data version for invoking function `watch`. Then I want to invoke a function `watch` to watch all operations (insert, update, and delete).

I know and it cost a lot of time to learn how to use [`db.collection.watch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/) function in MongoDB, and now I think I can watch a collection if you get me a collection name and the op id (of the [change stream](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/)) as the data version.

But I still do not know how to get the current op id when I invoke `db.collection.find`. I think I can open another change stream and get the recent op id and then close it. I think it sounds not good. But is there a better way to get op id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get an ugly code to solve it, but it works for me:

```golang
func (c *mongo.Collection) currentOpId(ctx context.Context) (opid storage.Opid, err error) {
    // Start to watch to get the ChangeStream.
    changeStream, err := c.Watch(ctx, mongodb.Pipeline{})
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("get change stream: %w", err)
        return
    }
    opidRaw := changeStream.ResumeToken()
    bson.Unmarshal(opidRaw, &opid)
    return
}
```